# 960.gs: Small offset nested columns

Tags: html, css, layout, offset, 960.gs

```
<div class="container_16">
<div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="grid_8 alpha search shadow">

    </div>
    <div class="grid_8 omega search shadow">

    </div>
</div>
```

With this code, the layout works but has a small offset to the right (3px or something like this). (search shadow are custom classes which just relate to the width and the background-image, no padding / margin etc.)

It looks like this:

[image]

What could be the reason?

**EDIT:**

Without using alpha and omega the layout floats into the next row! (2 boxes on the right side of the layout, one exactly over the other!)

Comment: Can you post the actual CSS too?  I can solve this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 960 grid framework the CSS class of "grid_8" has these CSS properties:

```
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
```

I'm sensing that you haven't gone through the CSS file of the 960 grid framework. I would recommend that you at least read what the classes you are using entail.

For instance:

```
/* `Grid >> Children (Alpha ~ First, Omega ~ Last)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.alpha {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.omega {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right. Solved it. Problem was I was using borders for debugging purposes which completely messed up my layout.